# How can i run php script with timer?

Tags: php, timer, foreach, countdown

I have foreach functions that print students names

```
$names = array("Alex","Brad","Tom");
foreach($names as $name) {
   echo "$name <br />";
   sleep(3);
}
```

How can i print each name, each 3 seconds? 
After `"echo $name"` i need some timer to stop the loop and wait for 3 seconds.
`sleep()` functions doesn't work here. What else i can do?

Comment: look on ob_flush() and flush()

Comment: Is this on the command line or on a web page?

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this server side (reliably). This is because there is just too much possibility of your traffic being held or buffered on the way: by the webserver, by proxies along the way, by your browser, etc. It would however probably work on CLI.

So I would definitely do it client-side, without sacrificing security (if needed).

If this is only for "cosmetic" purposes, you can create an AJAX method which will return the array of names, and then have Javascript output them with its timers.

Or, you could have AJAX call the PHP script using timers, and PHP will return only one name. It can save the current timestamp in the DB or in a Session variable, and don't return a new name until some time has passed.

Answer (score 3):

try using [flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) function

```
ob_start();    
$names = array("Alex","Brad","Tom");
foreach($names as $name) {
   echo "$name <br />";
   ob_flush();
   flush();    
   sleep(10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with javascript, ajax

or with flush() function

```
<?php
$names = array("Alex","Brad","Tom");
foreach($names as $name) {
   echo "$name <br />";
   flush();
   sleep(3);
}
```

[working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/f3498.php)

Comment: That's not true. You can do that, even if I think it's a bad practice.

Comment: @Fabio: It works for me in one server but not on second. How is it possible?

Comment: It depends on your php.ini configuration, try to add also an ob_flush() call.

Comment: look on php.ini php_value output_buffering "0"

Comment: Because in your first answer you've said that is not possible.

Comment: I edited your question (removing the offending line) and removed the downvote :-)

Comment: If you're using CLI flush() is not needed, original code will work as is.

Comment: @Fabio: And what does that "CLI" exactly mean? What is it? It'S some extension? Type of PHP?

Comment: [Command line interface](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) i.e. run php scripts from shell

Comment: It prints everything after 9 seconds (3 names x 3 seconds) , and before that the page is empty...

Comment: @user829149: it means you have to put output_buffering in php.ini OFF

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in a web page you need to flush the output or disable output buffering to get that work. Some references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

In php CLI that code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `flush();` after `echo`