# Is it possible to set a timer without clicking on the button?

Tags: php, html

How do i set Automatic timer on a button after 5 seconds (html)

Below is the code:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Refresh Page" style="font-size:100%""font-family:'Orator Std';" />
```

Comment: Here is the similar question and answers which can help you [click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6844889/1578908

Answer (score 2):

Emulate user click with JavaScript:

```
var click = setTimeout(function(){
    var button = document.getElementById('your-button-id');
    if (button) {
        button.click();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Add directly to the button with this:

```
onclick="setTimeout(function(){history.go(0);}, 5000);"
```

JavaScript only:

```
var history = setTimeout(function(){
    history.go(0);
}, 5000);
```

But why use `history.go(0);`? If you want to reload the page, use this:

```
var reload = setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.reload();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi Deep thanks, is it possible to set a timer without clicking on the button?

Comment: Make sure that you assign `setTimeout` to a variable so you can clear it if needed.